# JavaScript, CSS, get dynamic height from parent

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating some `div` that has 2 `div` inside.
The first `div` comes from a function called `borderDiv()` which return a `div` giving some classes depending on the arguments.

```
allData.map(data => {
  const isTwoRows = data.textToRender.length <= 50 && data.textToRender.length > 30;
  const isThreeRows = data.textToRender.length > 50;
  return (<div className="parent-border">
    {borderDiv(isTwoRows, isThreeRows)}
    <div>
      {data.textToRender}
    </div><
  /div>);
})
```

When receives `isTwoRows` the first `div` inside have classes that assign a `height` of 20px. When receives `isThreeRows` the height will be 40px.

It works ok on giving classes, so the function `borderDiv()` is working ok, but my problem is setting correctly the value for 2 or 3 rows.

Right now I'm just counting characters of the given string. If it's higher than 50, I will say that is `isThreeRows` or if it is ]30, 50] it will be `isTwoRows`.

I want to ask how could I set in a correct way the quantity of rows of text that the parent div (the div with class `parent-border`) has. Or in other words, get the height that has rendered the parent div of `borderDiv`. By getting that height, I could give as an argument to `borderDiv()` and then pick the correct class.

I tried to just set something like:

```
// in css:
.border-div {
    height: inherit;
}

<div className="parent-border">
    <div className="border-div">  // This will be the div rendered 
    <div>{data.textToRender}</div>
<(div>
```

Expecting to inherit the dynamic height of "parent-border" but this class has not a specific height, because it can change depending of how log the rendered text is. Example of rendered texts:

```
"a short text" <-- 1 row, so border-div height will be 20px

"a longer text that needs 
to me adapted" <--- 2 rows, so border div should be 40px
```

Any hint please.

Comment: Check out [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Comment: thans, https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-useref-forked-oguqk5 I made that sandbox for what I need and it works

Comment: Yay! Cheers and happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a built-in function called [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), which allows us to do precisely what you want—get the current width and height of an element.

```js
const { width, height } = $el.getBoundingClientRect();
// do something, e.g. (made up numbers)
const isTwoRows = height > 30 && height < 60;
const isThreeRows = height > 60 && height < 90;
```

[Awesome browser support.](https://caniuse.com/getboundingclientrect)

Comment: Thanks. That method helped me to my problem, which one like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-useref-forked-oguqk5?file=/src/index.js